# Does the equation have at most one solution in integers?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

The question is whether an equation $\dfrac{x+y}{xy}+ \dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ has more than one integer solution? The one integer solution is 1 and -1, so how can I prove that it is the only one?
I tried to factor the equation to prove that there will be no even division but it didn't work out. Also was idea to assume that there are integer solutions and try all possible solutions (x-even and y-odd, x-odd and y-even, both x,y-odd or even) by writing them down as 2n or 2n+1 and to show that there will the contradiction but it didn't work either.
Any help or hint would help a lot, thank you!

Comment: The expression on the left side is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$ and for $|x,y|\ge 5$ , we get $$|\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}|\le |\frac{1}{x}|+|\frac{1}{y}|+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\le 0.42$$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Peter, how can we say that this expression is small or equal to 0.42?

Comment: I inserted $x=y=5$ which gives the minimal denominators. Any other combination of denominators with $|x|,|y|\ge 5$ , must give a still smaller value.

Comment: @Peter, okay, thank you! But what happens if we have negative x and y? I inserted several negative x and y from (-infinity, 0) and the expression on left side is always negative, because we add a positive number (1/(x^2+y^2) to the negative sum (-1/x-1/y). And this number (1/(x^2+y^2) is less in absolute value and because of that the result will be negative. Is that correct?

Comment: This is just an answer to your question though you had asked for a method too but I also tried factorizing and failed, here's the answer anyways: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integer+solutions+%28x%2By%29%2Fxy%2B1%2F%28x2%2By2%29%3D1%2F2

Answer (score 2):

inequalities; graph the curve over the reals. There are two connected components.  Note that $x \neq 2, y \neq 2.$

Next, when $ x < -1,$ we find $1 < y < 2,$  so $y$ cannot be an integer.

When $ x \geq 7,$ we find $2 < y < 3,$  so $y$ cannot be an integer.

You may solve explicitly for $y$   for each remaining $x$  value, $-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6$  Let's see, when $x > 2$  we see $y > 2.$

Note that there is a little extra loop near the origin,  but that the only integer point is the origin,   which is not a legal $(x,y)$ position. So, the thing is not actually a hyperbola, but the inequalities are quite similar to that.

[image]